# How to make dependencies run after clean in gradle

Tags: gradle

Gradle 4.4

---

my `build.gradle` looks like this:

```
ext {
  project.dependencies.add(compile, somelibraries)
}

clean {
  delete "${WORKSPACE}/caches"
}

dependencies {
  ecj 'org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler:ecj:4.6.1'
  compile fileTree(dir: "${WORKSPACE}/lib", include: '*.jar')
}

task build1 {
  (loads extra libraries which I intend to delete using clean)
  (some compiling)
}
```

When I run `gradle -b build.gradle clean build1`,

1. it downloads dependencies first
2. and deletes it
3. and lastly returns error during `build1` because it just deleted dependencies.

---

**Problem**

I want to delete cache libraries that `build1` downloads, without changing the run command `gradle -b build.gradle clean build1`. Currently it also deletes default libraies since they share the same directory, which is not my intent.
Can I make `clean` run first before gradle invokes `dependencies` ?

Comment: Can I just randomly add another category like clean2{} and put it at the last? Will it run without changing the gradle execution command?